# Dynamicly change height of my Gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css

We are facing an issue with the height of a Gallery, we want the height to be changing according to the number of rows available.

Here is the link : http://numidiawebs.com/dev/hsth/maquette/galerie.html

we added a  right after the gallery finishes, with these values :

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

How ever, the footer is floating on top, and hiding a part of the gallery

so we fixed this problem by placing a second   (notice "clear2" ) and we gave a height to this **clear2 DIV** like this :

```
.clear2 {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 780px;
}
```

But now, the Gallery height isn't dynamic anymore :(

Can someone tell me how to fix this little issue,
Thank you in advance  ^^_

Answer (score 0):

aha i got it ., 
now look  , to make the gallery height is dynamic , don't miss with the height , just give a width , so that when u give the width for example 80%, if there are more photos on the gallery it will flow left, if the 80% was finished , so the second row will go down and complete the gallery . good luck

just in the style for the div use these primitive things

{
position:relative;float:left;width://for the image ;
}

leave the height for the main div , you can put a height for the pic itselef